# In AWS java version 2.10.4 , control hangs on initialisation of S3Client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk

After running the functionality,control hangs on initialisation of S3Client. Log file is stuck on below line :

```
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder().region(Region.EU_WEST_1).build();
```

Also, this is not giving any exceptions.

Comment: Please include your code and any stacktrace/output in your question. This will help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

It was because apache httpclient and httpcore version issue. As I updated them to 
below

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

It is working fine now.